# I am getting an error that I should not run script as root

Tags: server, drive

```
root@Lenovo:~/ardupilot# Tools/environment_install/install-prereqs-ubuntu.sh -y
```

While using the above command am getting this error:

```
---------- Tools/environment_install/install-prereqs-ubuntu.sh start ----------
+ '[' 0 == 0 ']'
+ echo 'Please do not run this script as root; don'\''t sudo it!'
Please do not run this script as root; don't sudo it!
+ exit 1
```

Comment: "root@Lenovo:~/ardupilot..." - "Please do not run this script as root". What exactly is your question? The script already told you why it refused to run.

Comment: why am getting this error what can i do to rectify this error

Comment: So did you try running not as root?

Comment: no i wanted to run in that directory

Comment: are you actually on Ubuntu?

Comment: yes am in ubuntu only am beginner to ubuntu

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu or Ubuntu app on Windows? Are yo using `sudo su` or `sudo -i` before running the script? If yes, trying without doing that.

Answer (score 2):

Look, you are signed in as the root user:

```
root@levono
```

Type `sudo su YOURUSERNAME` it will be changed to

```
YOURUSERNAME@levono
```

then execute the script.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a new user with just enough permissions to get the job done, then run this script with that user. The way this account is made will depend on which distribution of Linux is being used here, along with the types of permissions necessary to run the script, but there should be options for this in the Settings menu and terminal, respectively.

Running scripts directly from Root is a security hazard. Since Root doesn't have any restrictions, if the account happened to get infected with malware and hacked, the entire system would be compromised. I have reason to believe the whole point of the error is to prevent exactly this.